# When a function with two variable separable?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, convex-analysis

Suppose we have two functions $f$ and $g$. Both are functions of variable $x$ and $y$. My question is under what condition $g$ can be represented as a convex combination of $f$ and a function $h$ which is only a function of $y$?

So, when is it possible to have $g$ of the following the form? $$g(x,y)=tf(x,y)+(1-t)h(y),~t\in[0,1].$$
Two immediate cases are when $t=0$ or $1$.(in casese where $g=f$ or $g=h$). Is there any other general result on this decomposition?